# I got confused with pointers for multiple value returning in function, C/C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I know how to write this code correctly, but I got confused about how it is doing it!

Look at this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float quardarticFunction(float, float, float, float*, float*); 

float a, b, c, resultOne, resultTwo;
     
int main(){
    cout << "Lets write a function to calculate quadratic function" << endl;
    cout << "Please write a, b and c in order: ";
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    quardarticFunction(a, b, c, &resultOne, &resultTwo);
    cout << "First X is: " << resultOne << " And the second X is: " << resultTwo << endl;
    return 0;               
} 

float quardarticFunction(float a, float b, float c, float *xOne, float *xTwo){
    *xOne = ((-1 * b) + sqrt((b * b) - (4 * a * c)))/(2 * a);
    *xTwo = ((-1 * b) - sqrt((b * b) - (4 * a * c)))/(2 * a);
}
```

So for explaining my confusion I will describe my code a little bit ( please tell where I am wrong!)

first in this function:

```cpp
float quardarticFunction(float a, float b, float c, float *xOne, float *xTwo){

    *xOne = ((-1 * b) + sqrt((b * b) - (4 * a * c)))/(2 * a);
    *xTwo = ((-1 * b) - sqrt((b * b) - (4 * a * c)))/(2 * a);
}
```

I know that `float* xOne, float* xTwo` are pointers and they are given as arguments. and `*` inside the body of the function is dereference operator.

before the `main` we use prototype and its crystal clear.

Then inside the body of `main`, I called the function and gave it resultOne and resultTwo variables addresses. I don't know I am wrong or right **(Please tell me if I am wrong!)**, but for me, it's like this example:

```cpp
int sampleOne;
int* sampleTwo = &sampleTwo;
```

Then for accessing data I have written:

`cout << "First X is: " << resultOne << " And the second X is: " << resultTwo << endl;`

**where my main problem comes from here!**

How my variables get this data from pointer and addresses.

I don't want another way to write my code, I just want to know why its like that!

Comment: This is clearly not C

Comment: @CacahueteFrito, its C++ but I think the concept is the same with C.

Comment: OT: `quardartic` -> `quadratic`. More on topic, you declared a function returning a `float`, but it does not return anything.

Comment: There are two things called “xOne”, and their types are different. The same for “xTwo”. Don’t use the same names for the global variables and the parameters and it gets easier to follow.

Comment: @molbdnilo, Sorry my mistake

Comment: I rolled back the edit.

Comment: @RemyLebeau , Now I found what was the problem

Answer (score 3):

You are confused by poor naming. Globally you have `xOne` and `xTwo` which are of type `float`. In the function you have two completely different variables that are also called `xOne` and `xTwo`, but they are pointers.

```
float a, b, c, xOne, xTwo;   // floats

float quardarticFunction(float a, float b, float c, float* xOne, float* xTwo)
                                                       ^ pointer to float
```

Consider to write `float* xOne` rather than `float *xOne`, because the `*` is part of the type, not of the name. And perhaps naming the function arguments differently will make the code more clear.

To get the value of a `float` you need not dereference anything.

To get the value of the `float` that a `float*` points to, you need to dereference the `float*`.

Comment: Thank you, Now I see whats is my problem is. So you are saying, variable addresses are going to function and then the values go to the variable and I am printing them right?

Answer (score 2):

They are not pointers in the main function. They are global variables that are accessed directly. You pass the addresses of these two memory locations when you prefix them with ampersands(&) in the function call.

In the function itself, you define the last two parameters using the same names as the global variables, overriding them in the scope of the function. The function-scope variables are pointers to the memory locations and have to be accessed as such.

Answer (score 1):

From the point of view of the quadratic function, the `xONe` and the `xTwo` are pointers, right. On the other hand, you have declared them as float in your `main` . That's why you have passed them to the function with `&` operator, which means send their addresses(pointers) to the function so that the function will have the pointers to `xOne` and `xTwo`. Being a float, not a pointer, in the main function for `xOne` and `xTwo` is also the reason why you used with cout as in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You declared XOne and XTwo as float variables not as a pointer to a float variable so you don't have to deference them with the * operator when you print them out